# ERROR: Attempt to remove an object that's already been removed

Tags: lua, coronasdk

I am having this error popping up when i restart the game :

(ERROR: Attempt to remove an object that's already been removed from the stage or whose parent/ancestor group has already been removed.)

I am using jet:removeSelf() in a function called by a collision (code below)

```
function explode()
Runtime:removeEventListener("enterFrame", moveJet)  
Runtime:removeEventListener("enterFrame", wrap)
jet:removeSelf()
end

local function onCollision(event)
    if event.phase == "began" and gameIsActive == true then
        local obj1 = event.object1; 
        local obj2 = event.object2; 

    if obj1.name == "jetplayer" and obj2.name == "BCloud1" then   
        explode()
        end
    end
end
    Runtime:addEventListener( "collision", onCollision )
```

So the game works fine the first time but not when you restart. any ideas on how to fix the problem ?

Comment: are you using storyboard?

Comment: yes i am using storyboard

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to remove your scene after you go to another scene that way it will create all the object including the values when you restart your game or you put your jet object to a group and when the group is remove you remove the jet object too

Comment: im using "storyboard.removeScene( "game" )" in gameover.lua same error + i am using "storyboard.purgeOnSceneChange = true" in the mail.lua file

Comment: are you sure the explode() function causes the error because i think your code is fine

Comment: yes i looks that way its calling the "jet:removeSelf()" the second time and you get this : ERROR: Attempt to remove an object that's already been removed from the stage or whose parent/ancestor group has already been removed.

Comment: if so then you need you need to reinitialize the jet object from createScene because i think it's trying to remove it and the jet object has already been remove from the first time

Comment: the code for the jet is in the 'function scene:createScene( event )....end' code block

Comment: can you add some more code may be then we can see where the problem actually occuring

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17497654/error-attempt-to-remove-an-object-thats-already-been-removed/17498132#17498132

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/32981/discussion-between-devfar-and-kevin-ver)